# Filter Ionic Accordion List

Tags: angularjs, filter, ionic-framework, accordion, angularjs-filter

I am developing an app using Ionic and at some point I have an accordion list showing the names of professions and their specialties, like this:

- Profession 1

  - Specialty 1
  - Specialty 2
- Profession 2

  - Specialty 3
  - Specialty 4

I need to filter this list according to the specialties only and, if possible, I would like to keep all the groups (that have specialties that match the given seach value) showing when the user is typing into the search box.

Here is my view:

```
<ion-view view-title="Specialty">
    <ion-content>
        <div class="list list-inset">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search Specialty" ng-model="seachSpecialty">
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="list">
            <div ng-repeat="profession in professions">
                <div class="item item-icon-left"  ng-click="toggleGroup(profession)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(profession)}">
                    <i class="icon icon-accessory" ng-class="isGroupShown(profession) ? 'ion-chevron-up' : 'ion-chevron-down'"></i>
                    &nbsp;
                    {{profession.name}}
                </div>
                <div class="item item-icon-left item-accordion" ng-show="isGroupShown(profession)" ng-repeat="specialty in profession.specialties">
                    {{specialty.name}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And this is my Controller:

```
    .controller('SpecialtyCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicHistory, $ionicLoading, DataSource) {

    $scope.professions = DataSource.getProfessions();

    $scope.toggleGroup = function (group) {
        if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
            $scope.shownGroup = null;
        } else {
            $scope.shownGroup = group;
        }
    }

    $scope.isGroupShown = function (group) {
        return $scope.shownGroup === group;
    }
})
```

EDIT:

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nHupW22o0RmmJ1yqe3Ba) corresponding to this code.

All about the accordion list is working (expanding and collapsing). My question is how to make a filter in this list to only filter the subitens (specialties) of the list? What a custom filter for this list would look like? Is it possible to keep the groups expanded while the list is filtered?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem or what your question is. Does it work? You'd have more chances if you provide a plunkr for this.

Comment: Your plunkr doesn't work at all. At least the controller is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use Angular [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

First you inject the filter so it can be used in your controller:

```
myApp.controller('SpecialtyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter',
function($scope, $http, $filter) {

    var filter = $filter('filter');
```

Then you extend your controller logic like this:

```
    function hasMatchingSpecialities(group) {
        return $scope.searchSpecialty &&
            filter(group.specialties,
                {name: $scope.searchSpecialty}).length;
    }

    $scope.isGroupShown = function (group) {
        return $scope.shownGroup === group ||
            hasMatchingSpecialities(group);
    }
```

The `ng-repeat` for your specialities can be extended to use the filter:

```
<div class="item item-icon-left item-accordion" ng-show="isGroupShown(profession)"
  ng-repeat="specialty in profession.specialties | filter: searchSpecialty">
                {{specialty.name}}
</div>
```

This is the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tjkm95XdKL2jkDfQ3EJR?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I needed and even better: without having to implement a custom filter. Neat trick with the `isGroupShown(group)` function.